# How to approach Java OOP program

Tags: java, class, oop

I am a college student currently learning OOP in Java.
I have been given a fairly difficult assignment and as I am 
very new to OOP it's proving quite tough. I'll firstly give an overview of
what I've been asked to do & then the details of where I'm currently at with it.

The program we have been asked to implement is an application of a doctors surgery to manage
the relationship between Doctors & Patients. A fully operational GUI is required but I will avoid starting that for now as it will only complicate matters.

The following is the assignment spec:

---

"Develop an application to manage a doctor’s surgery.

1. The doctor will have to be authenticated to gain access to the system.
2. The doctor will be presented with a list of their patients when they login.
3. The doctor will need to review a patient’s details, update patients details, add new patients.
   a.  Patient details include, name, address, number, patient history (details of each visit/procedure/serious illness + dates)
   b.  up to week 8 we will use an arraylist to store the data. This will be persisted to a file at shutdown, and loaded in at start up.
   c.  After week 8  a database should be used to replace the arraylist and any files used previously for persistance.
4. The doctor should be able to search for a patient under patient name or patient id
5. Backup and Restore : In the event of a disaster where the database is corrupted or destroyed the system will need to be restored from a backup. The doctor will need to be able to backup all system information to a file and restore from this file if necessary. The file should be labelled with the date of backup, the backup should be done weekly.
6. Two reports should be generated one is just a list of all patients in the system followed by their history(ordered alphabetically on patient name), and secondly a report on all patients who visited between certain dates ordered on date.
   "

---

So far I have managed to create the classes and my code is as follows (we have been given class-diagrams to work from).

Surgery class (main):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class surgery
{
    private int surgeryId;
    private String surgeryAdd;    

    public surgery(int surgeryId, String surgeryAdd)
    {
      this.surgeryId = surgeryId;
      this.surgeryAdd = surgeryAdd;
    }

    public void setId (int surgeryId) {            
        this.surgeryId = surgeryId;                 
    }

    public void setSurgeryAdd (String surgeryAdd) {             
        this.surgeryAdd = surgeryAdd;             
    }

    public int getId () {         
        return surgeryId;         
    }

    public String getSurgeryAdd () {         
        return surgeryAdd;         
    }                              

    public static void main(String[] args) {                         

        System.out.println("Add doctor, enter name: ");
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);

        //User inputs name
        String enteredName = kbd.nextLine();

       //Object is then created with an ID number and the name the user entered:
        Doctor one = new Doctor (1, enteredName);

        //Create ArrayList to store Doctor objects:
        ArrayList<Doctor> myDoctors = new ArrayList();

        //Add the first doctor to ArrayList:
        myDoctors.add(one);

        //Print out the doctors array.
        System.out.print(myDoctors);                                                                         
    }                  
}
```

Doctor Class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Doctor
{
   private int doctorId;
   private String doctorName;
   ArrayList <Patient> patients = new ArrayList();            

    public Doctor(int doctorId, String doctorName)
    {
       this.doctorId = doctorId ;
       this.doctorName = doctorName;             
    }

    public void setId (int doctorId) {             
        this.doctorId = doctorId;         
    }

    public void setName (String doctorName) {         
        this.doctorName = doctorName;         
    }

    public int getId (){         
        return doctorId;         
    }

    public String getName () {         
        return doctorName;             
    }

    public String toString () {         
        return "Doctor ID: "+doctorId+", Doctor name: "+doctorName;         
    }                

    public void addPatient (int patientId, String name, String address, String phoneNumber, Date DOB ) {

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a patient ID: ");

        int id = kbd.nextInt();

        kbd.nextLine();             

        System.out.print("Enter patient Name: ");
        String patientName = kbd.nextLine();


        System.out.print("Enter Address:");
        String patientAddress = kbd.nextLine();


        System.out.print("Enter the phone num:");
        String num = kbd.nextLine();


        Date dateOfBirth = new Date(1);

        Patient pat = new Patient(id, patientName, patientAddress, num, dateOfBirth);

        patients.add(pat);

        System.out.println(patients);                                              
    }
```

Patient Class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Patient
{
   private int patientId;
   private String patientName;
   private String patientAddress;
   private String patientPhone;
   private Date patientDOB;                  

    public Patient(int patientId, String patientName, String patientAddress, String patientPhone, Date patientDOB)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.patientId = patientId;
        this.patientName = patientName;
        this.patientAddress = patientAddress;
        this.patientPhone = patientPhone;
        this.patientDOB = patientDOB;

    }

    public void setId (int patientId) {

        this.patientId = patientId;

    }

    public void setName (String patientName){

        this.patientName = patientName;

    }

    public void setAddress (String patientAddress){

        this.patientAddress = patientAddress;

    }

    public void setPhone (String patientPhone){

        this.patientPhone = patientPhone;

    }

    public void setDOB (Date patientDOB){

        this.patientDOB = patientDOB;

    }

    public int getId () {

           return patientId;

    }

    public String getName () {

            return patientName;   

    }

    public String getAddress () {

        return patientAddress;

    }

    public String getPhone () {

        return patientPhone;

    }

    public Date getDOB () {

        return patientDOB;

    }




}                        

}
```

Patient History Class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class patientHistory
{

   int historyId;
   int patientId;
   int doctorId;
   Date visitDate;
   String description;
   String medicine;
   String procedure;                

    public patientHistory(int historyId, int patientId, int doctorId, Date visitDate, String description, String medicine, String procedure)
    {
      this.historyId = historyId;
      this.patientId = patientId;
      this.doctorId = doctorId;
      this.visitDate = visitDate;
      this.description = description;
      this.medicine = medicine;
      this.procedure = procedure;
    }

    public void setHistoryId (int historyId){

        this.historyId = historyId;

    }

    public void setPatientId (int patientId) {

        this.patientId = patientId;

    }


    public void setDoctorId (int doctorId) {

        this.doctorId = doctorId;

    }

    public void setVisitDate (Date visitDate){

        this.visitDate = visitDate;

    }

    public void setDescription (String description) {

        this.description = description;

    }

    public void setmedicine (String medicine){

        this.medicine = medicine;

    }

    public void setProcedure (String procedure){

        this.procedure = procedure;

    }

    public int getHistoryId () {

        return historyId;

    }

    public int getPatientId () {

        return patientId;

    }

    public int getDoctorId () {

        return doctorId;

    }

    public Date getVisitDate () {

        return visitDate;


    }

    public String getDescription () {

        return description;

    }

    public String getMedicine () {

        return medicine;

    }

    public String getProcedure () {

        return procedure;

    }                           

}
```

When first doing procedural programming I struggled also but evetually managed to get a decent grasp of most of the concepts. With OOP, it feels as though I'm back to square one and every answer I search for seems to complicate it further for me. I understand the concpet of OOP but struggle with the implementation. Often I do not know where to 'place things'.

For example in the doctor class I have made the first method. (addPatient) but I simply don't know how to set up the relationship between doctors and patients. I don't understand where to call the method (is it the surgery class (main), the doctor class itself etc. etc.)

I'm not asking for code,
I am basically seeking advice on how to procede from here as this is due in about 4 weeks time.

Thanks.

Comment: have a look here, maybe you will get more ideas http://micajeudy.hubpages.com/hub/Object-Oriented-Systems-Development-Life-Cycle

Answer (score 1):

Try to think of classes as completetly isolated components, this will improve reusability which is something OOP aims for. Question yourself whether the implementation will work in different environments. For example Doctor.addPatient() should not prompt for details about the patient you want to add (that information is already given to you as paramenters).

Once you have the main elements identified think of how you're going to glue everything together. As others have pointed out you should take a look at Design Patterns (for example MVC which is great when dealing with GUI).

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are taking is starting to write code in the beginning.
First take the time to think what you are going to make and design your application.
Two tips:
 1. Create UML diagrams (you only have class diagrams?)
 2. Define your [Domain Models](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/domain-driven-design--net-25773)

You will see thing may be different than you first thought.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about the role of your classes. I see that `Doctor.addPatient()` takes input from the user, but it is not its role. Instead, the UI code (in your case, the main method) should create the patient and then call `addPatient()` with the new patient as an argument. That way, the `Doctor` class will still work when you make your GUI.

Answer (score -1):

To approach OOP programming in an optimal way, you should be aware of various Design Patterns.
Knowledge of various Creational Design Patterns, Behavioral Design Patterns, and Structural Design Patterns helps a lot while architecting the solution to any problem.

Comment: -1 If you struggle with basic OOP concepts, trying to use GoF patterns will not lead to better design. Quite the opposite.

Comment: Knowledge of Design Patterns also helps in understanding OOP concepts. So I don't see any mutual exclusion between OOP concepts and Design Patterns that are used in OOP.